# How to connect Vertx RedisClient cluster mode disabled with Elasticache

Tags: redis, vert.x, amazon-elasticache

We are using Vertx Redis client from the package io.vertx.redis.client to connect to AWS Elasticache Redis (Cluster Mode Disabled) Cluster.

We see that our read commands are not being split between the different cluster nodes, even when we are using the reader endpoint (reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Endpoints.html)

We saw this example, (reference - [How to connect Vertx RedisClient in cluster mode with Elasticache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57248290/how-to-connect-vertx-redisclient-in-cluster-mode-with-elasticache)), for using the client with Cluster Mode Enabled, but couldn't figure out how to make it work for Cluster Mode Disabled.

Did anyone managed to get Vertx client to work with Elasticache Redis (Cluster Mode Disabled) Cluster?

We have also tried this example from Vertx documentation, (reference - https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-redis-client/java/#_high_availability_mode), we have used `.setRole(RedisRole.SENTINEL))` (in order to configure client for read operations only), and for the `.addConnectionString()` configuration we have provided the endpoints of each node in the cluster.

Thanks,
Lior